# elasticsearch findAll with pageable

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to get all documents with pageable, but i get this error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was
>   java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain:
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.aggregation.impl.AggregatedPageImpl["facets"])

**Repository**

```
public interface ConventionSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Convention, Long> {
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ConventionServiceImpl implements ConventionService {

  private final ConventionSearchRepository conventionSearchRepository;

   @Override
   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public Page<Convention> findAll(final PageRequest pageable) {
     return conventionSearchRepository.findAll(pageable);
   }

}
```

**Controller**

```
  @GetMapping("/conventions")
  public Page<Convention> getAllConventions(@RequestParam(value = "_page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int page,
      @RequestParam(value = "_perPage", required = false, defaultValue = "20") int perPage,
      @RequestParam(value = "_sortDir", required = false, defaultValue = "DESC") Sort.Direction sortDir,
      @RequestParam(value = "_sortBy", required = false, defaultValue = "shortname") String sortBy) {
    Sort sort = new Sort(sortDir, sortBy);
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, perPage, sort);
    return conventionService.findAll(pageRequest);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to simply declare a org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable parameter to my @Controller and then pass it directly to my service and then ultimately the @Repository (I extend it with a CustomRepository).   Spring takes care of populating all the details about the sort parameters and such.   I didn't have to verbosely define the separate @RequestParams.

Here's an example

```
public Page<LogEntry> findAllLogEntries(@PageableDefault(page = DEFAULT_PAGE, size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) @SortDefault.SortDefaults({@SortDefault(sort = "@timestamp", direction = Direction.DESC)}) Pageable pageable) {
```

I'm on Spring 5 and Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.5.RELEASE